# Weak isospin 1/2 vector bosons

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction

The weak vector bosons are spacetime vectors (spin 1) and also incidentally weak isospin vector components (-1, 0, +1). I understand why that is required from nucleon beta decay and other weak interaction decays.   Experimentally there are no weak interactions that I'm aware of that require a weak boson field that is a spacetime vector but a weak isospin spinor  (weak isospins of +-1/2). Is there a sound *theoretical* reason to exclude such a field from the interaction Lagrangian density, e.g. no suitable term can be made? I have not seen it discussed anywhere, but perhaps just haven't found the right reference yet.

Comment: massless spin-1 particles must be gauge bosons, and the gauge bosons must transform in the adjoint representation of the group, hence the gauge bosons of SU(2) are necesserily triplets (and gluons as 8 of SU(3)...). Non-massless spin-1 particles could in principle transform in other representations, but then their mass would be most likely at around the cutoff of the theory that would not be renormalizable.

Comment: @TwoBS: if I'm reading your comment correctly does that mean that the representing space of the adjoint rep of SU(2) is 3d in order to get a triplet?

Comment: @MoziburUllah yes, the adjoint of SU(2) is a 3-dimensional representation.

Comment: @TwoBS: ok, thanks; it's the term triplet I was confused about, my background is math rather than a physics; to press on, does this mean that the adjoint rep of SU(3) is 8d, and so we have an octet of gluons?

Comment: @MoziburUllah yes, precisely. There are 8 gluons because the adjoint of SU(3) color is 8-dimensional.

Comment: @TwoBs: and so Gellmans eightfold way! Great, thanks it's cleared up some confusion of mine.

Comment: @MoziburUllah in fact, no, I am sorry: the eightfold way refers to another 8. It refers to chiral symmetry breaking in the strong interactions: $SU(3)_L \times SU(3)_R$ is broken spontaneously down to the diagonal $SU(3)_{L+R}$, to be identified with the strong isospin. By the goldstone theorem there arise 8+8-8=8 goldstone bosons which trasform in the adjoint of the strong isospin group $SU(3)_{L+R}$ .

Comment: @TwoBs: Nothing to be sorry about, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @TwoBs  Well, the K*s are vector meson  (strong-)iso-doublets, but they would not purport to be gauge bosons or to mediate any weak interactions. It's hard to fathom the OP's intent: he wants to ignore the crushing weight of half a century of evidence for a theoretical 2-generator option... for the 1D affine group (which has 2 generators)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I think I am not understanding your comment. The K* are indeed very close to the cutoff and there is no way to deform QCD or come with another theory that would bring them parametrically below the proton mass.

Comment: @TwoBs. ? Who cares about the proton mass? The question is likely not to model the 4-Fermi theory for the weak interactions, a book closed for half a century now,  since the theory has been  verified past several TeVs, but to seek mystery 2-generator non-abelian gauge groups for obscure purposes, no? You appear to be thinking about effective QFTs, but why?

Comment: @TwoBs, would you mind expanding on your comment about the problems with massive vector bosons if I write a separate question? I've heard people mention things like this in passing and never understood what goes wrong.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understood the question as a purely academic one, as it is obvious, e.g., that experimentally we have 3 spin-1 weak-isospin bosons ($W^{\pm}$ and $Z$).  Can one imagine, in principle, a theory for spin-1 bosons that are weak-isospin doublet? The answer is: yes, but the  price to pay is a non-renormalizable theory with a very low cutoff (that's why I was thinking to EFT).

Comment: @octonion I wouldn't certainly mind, but I do lack time and that's why a rarely write extended answers and limit myself instead to comments. But give it a try, perhaps I will menage to find the time to answer it (if I can!) , and in any case someone else maybe will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. @TwoB, re the initial reply I believe that the requirement for the gauge bosons to transform as the adjoint rep comes from the need to end up with a scalar lagrangian density, and the fact that normally there is a product of the field with the su(2) (lie alg) generators to cause this.   So I guess the  question is in those terms whether any other reasonable way to create a scalar term from SU(2) or su(2) and the field reps exists, although, as we all agree, the current one has been pretty well verified by experiment.   Possibly something considered by Pauli, Yang and Mills and the others when the theory was forming but discarded by them. Apparently not considered in print so far as I've found.  And yes, as someone noticed the motivation is to see if some valid possibility has been overlooked that might help get us out of the tight corner we've painted ourselves into with the SM.

Comment: Waitwaitwait: what "tight corner we've painted ourselves into with the SM"? Many physicists just can't get enough of the unremitting success of the SM. As  indicated, purely formally, a vector isodoublet field can saturate a spinor isodoublet and a spinor isosinglet to produce a Lorentz invariant coupling term invariant under SU(2) as well. It just won't be part of a renormalizable or realistic theory. The vector field won't be a gauge field, unless you switch your group to the 1d affine group, with just 1 nontrivial commutation relation involving the 2 sole generators.

Comment: Thanks, Cosmas, that helps.  The "...corner." comment of mine was out of line and takes things into the realm of discussion which is not the purpose here.  Sorry.